# IE: Choose a digital certificate from a blank, empty list

Tags: internet-explorer, iis, ssl, safari, certificate

I've created a web application that I've hosted with IIS 7 on a Windows Server 2008 machine.  I've loaded a security certificate for secure.xxxxx.com.

[IIS 7 Server Certificates http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/324/certxx6.gif](http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/324/certxx6.gif)

When I browse to the web site with **Microsoft Internet Explorer**, I get this prompt:

> Choose a digital certificate
>   Identification
>   The website you want to view requests identification.
>   Please choose a certificate.

There are no certificates.  It's an empty, blank list.

[image: Internet Explorer Choose a digital certificate]

If I click either OK or Cancel, then the page loads just fine.  There's no warning or other indication from Internet Explorer that there is a security issue.

[Microsoft Internet Explorer SSL Security Certificate Website Identification http://img207.imageshack.us/img207/8265/ie2yr5.gif](http://img207.imageshack.us/img207/8265/ie2yr5.gif)

The **Apple Safari** browser won't display the page at all.

> Safari can't open the page.
>   Safari can't open the page xxxxx because
>   it couldn't establish a secure connection
>   to the server xxxxx.

[Apple Safari can't open the page http://img80.imageshack.us/img80/2899/safka3.gif](http://img80.imageshack.us/img80/2899/safka3.gif)

Both **Mozilla Firefox** and **Google Chrome** load the web site perfectly with no hassles.

[Mozilla Firefox SSL Security Certificate http://img158.imageshack.us/img158/6833/foxsk4.gif](http://img158.imageshack.us/img158/6833/foxsk4.gif)

[Google Chrome SSL Security Certificate http://img367.imageshack.us/img367/7928/chrsx2.gif](http://img367.imageshack.us/img367/7928/chrsx2.gif)

Why might Microsoft Internet Explorer and Apple Safari fail to load my web site properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution at [forums.iis.net](http://forums.iis.net/t/1151141.aspx).

In IIS I modified the SSL Settings for my web site.

[IIS SSL Settings icon http://img183.imageshack.us/img183/8808/ssl1uc7.gif](http://img183.imageshack.us/img183/8808/ssl1uc7.gif)

I changed "Client certificates" from "Accept" to "Ignore".

**Before:**

[IIS SSL Settings accept client certificates http://img185.imageshack.us/img185/548/ssl2om9.gif](http://img185.imageshack.us/img185/548/ssl2om9.gif)

**After:**

[IIS SSL Settings ignore client certificates http://img185.imageshack.us/img185/4945/ssl3kx6.gif](http://img185.imageshack.us/img185/4945/ssl3kx6.gif)

The web site now loads perfectly in Microsoft Internet Explorer and Apple Safari as well as Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

A SSL connection where the server presents a certificate and the user is required to present a certificate is considered 2-way SSL. Governments and businesses are the ones who usually use it the most.