# IE: Choosing a digital certificate from a blank list every first visit to my website

Tags: internet-explorer, iis, ssl, certificate, virtual-machine

I have an ASP.NET 4 WebForms website running off IIS 7, we have three versions: local development versions, test versions and production.

All three use SSL certificates. We have three different certificates for each environment.

If I wanted to load up my VM with IE7 installed, and go to my local development version, for the first visit I always get this message. Selecting OK or Cancel proceeds to the page without any issue.

[image: IE7 Digital Certificate blank empty list]

I've already tried the solution offered here, but it did not work:
[IE: Choose a digital certificate from a blank, empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205244/ie-choose-a-digital-certificate-from-a-blank-empty-list)

IE8 works fine.

Does anybody have any clues as to why I get this box?

The certificate for our local development version is installed into IIS and is installed into the Virtual machine also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As far as I understand, you're asking why you get this box at all, not why the list is empty.)

You'll get this box when the server requests a client certificate. You probably have configured your server (or one of the application it's running) to request client-certificate authentication (perhaps optionally). If turning it off as an IIS option doesn't work, perhaps the code you're running is making that request. In addition, you could check with `netsh http show sslcert` whether `Negotiate Client Certificate` is enabled.

If you're not planning to use this feature, that is, if you're not expecting your users to authenticate using a certificate, turn this off.